# MySQL Group before order?

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a sql query to obtain the results order by text column where id=1 or 2 or 3.
While keeping the id sequence the same.
Hope there is any kind help on the below:

My Table:

```
id  record  text
1   1       Apple
2   1       Fruits
3   1       Nice
1   2       Mango
2   2       Fruits
3   2       Moderate
1   3       Car
2   3       Vehicles
3   3       Nice
```

Intended results if ordered by id=1

```
id  record  text
1   1       Apple
2   1       Fruits
3   1       Nice
1   3       Car
2   3       Vehicles
3   3       Nice
1   2       Mango
2   2       Fruits
3   2       Moderate
```

or
Intended results if ordered by id=2

```
id  record  text
1   1       Apple
2   1       Fruits
3   1       Nice
1   2       Mango
2   2       Fruits
3   2       Moderate
1   3       Car
2   3       Vehicles
3   3       Nice
```

or
Intended results if ordered by id=3

```
id  record  text
1   2       Mango
2   2       Fruits
3   2       Moderate
1   1       Apple
2   1       Fruits
3   1       Nice
1   3       Car
2   3       Vehicles
3   3       Nice
```

Comment: You mean record = 1 !?!?!?!

Comment: I'm not sure it is record instead, if we treat record as a whole record set then yes. Important here is to be able to sort by text column according to the id specified, and the id sequence should be remain in sequence.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry what i mean is as the above table.
Where the sequence of the id is always 1,2,3 but the record will be sorted according to the id specified.

Comment: Thats fine. I just haven't the faintest idea what you're driving at.

Comment: OK. Now I get it - but it's an appalling explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL 
,record  INT NOT NULL
,text VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,record)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   ,1       ,'Apple'),
(2   ,1       ,'Fruits'),
(3   ,1       ,'Nice'),
(1   ,2       ,'Mango'),
(2   ,2       ,'Fruits'),
(3   ,2       ,'Moderate'),
(1   ,3       ,'Car'),
(2   ,3       ,'Vehicles'),
(3   ,3       ,'Nice');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+--------+----------+
| id | record | text     |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | Apple    |
|  1 |      2 | Mango    |
|  1 |      3 | Car      |
|  2 |      1 | Fruits   |
|  2 |      2 | Fruits   |
|  2 |      3 | Vehicles |
|  3 |      1 | Nice     |
|  3 |      2 | Moderate |
|  3 |      3 | Nice     |
+----+--------+----------+

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.record = x.record 
   AND y.id = 3 
 ORDER 
    BY y.text
     , x.record
     , x.id;
+----+--------+----------+
| id | record | text     |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      2 | Mango    |
|  2 |      2 | Fruits   |
|  3 |      2 | Moderate |
|  1 |      1 | Apple    |
|  2 |      1 | Fruits   |
|  3 |      1 | Nice     |
|  1 |      3 | Car      |
|  2 |      3 | Vehicles |
|  3 |      3 | Nice     |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks... I'll need sometime to digest... Let me sometime and get back to you...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer GURU!!! The query is so short and compact which i will never think of.

Comment: +1 . . . I wouldn't write it this way.  Quite clever.